# Expand PV on FC SAN - Linux doesn't see new size without reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, storage-area-network

Got Infortrend SAN attached through fiber channel to Ubuntu 10.04 Server. The HBA is Qlogic QLE2562.
After expanding the LUN on the SAN, the server still shows the old size. If I reboot the server, its partitions table gets updated. However, I can't do this now. I am looking for way to do this without reboot.

I use `multipath` and LVM, no partitions on SAN LUNs. `partprobe -s` shows only locally attached drives (`/dev/sda and /dev/sdb`). Tried [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/66638/how-to-extend-a-san-based-vdisk-in-red-hat-without-rebooting) but got:

```
multipathd> resize map mpath13
multipath-tools v0.4.8 (08/02, 2007)
CLI commands reference:
 list|show paths
 list|show maps|multipaths
 list|show maps|multipaths status
 list|show maps|multipaths stats
 list|show maps|multipaths topology
 list|show topology
 list|show map|multipath $map topology
 list|show config
 list|show blacklist
 list|show devices
 add path $path
 remove|del path $path
 add map|multipath $map
 remove|del map|multipath $map
 switch|switchgroup map|multipath $map group $group
 reconfigure
 suspend map|multipath $map
 resume map|multipath $map
 reinstate path $path
 fail path $path
```

Apparently there is no `resize map` command.

Please advice.

Thank you.

Comment: Your system is probably too old, or Ubuntu explicitly removed the command.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

If have a multipath disk call mpatha with two path sdb and sdc, first i need to resize the LUN on san and after that, you need to go on your system and give the following commands

echo 1 > /sys/block/sdb/device/rescan

echo 1 > /sys/block/sdc/device/rescan

multipathd -k'resize map mpatha'

Now you can verify the new size of mpatha with multipath -ll mpatha

Comment: I already tried this, the `multipathd -k 'resize map mpatha' command is not available on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: are you sure you don't have this command on ubuntu? ummm i saw in your post you was using the multipath command line, you need to use multipathd -k'resize map <put_here_the_device_you_find_with_multipath -ll>'